# XSS with local storage - Is it a concern?

Tags: javascript, html5

I am working on creating a demo of how to use HTML5's local storage. The demo will be placed on my personal website and will append the user submitted data to the html. Can XSS stored on the client negatively affect my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a new technology, and should not be used for any sort of production.

http://michael-coates.blogspot.com/2010/07/html5-local-storage-and-xss.html

Please read the comments to further judge whether this is a good idea.

Comment: I am making a demo of how to use local storage on my website so it is not for production. My concern is that can XSS in local storage negatively hurt my website's reputation / rank.

Comment: @Jordan - When you implement this, as long as your server is clean (the XSS is only on the visitor's machine, so it's non-persistent XSS) then it should have no effect on the rankings.